# Can't log in/out or register, and my submitPost function stopped working

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Grunt gives me no errors

and under the debugger

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- user <- NavCtrl
```

and

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- user
```

This is the auth service https://github.com/Eibonic/AngularJS-reddit/blob/master/app/scripts/services/Auth.js

and this is the nav controller

```
'use strict';

app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post, Auth){
    $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
    $scope.signedIn = Auth.signedIn;

    $scope.submitPost = function () {
        Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref){
            $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
            $location.path('/posts/' + ref.name());
            });
            };

            $scope.logout = function () {
                Auth.logout();
            };
});
```

And this is the auth controller.

```
'use strict';

app.controller('AuthCtrl',
 function ($scope, $location, Auth) {
    if (Auth.signedIn()) {
        $location.path('/');
    }

    $scope.login = function () {
        Auth.login($scope.user).then(function () {
            $location.path('/');
        });
    };

    $scope.register = function () {
        Auth.register($scope.user).then(function () {
            return Auth.login($scope.user).then(function() {
                $location.path('/');
            });
        });
    };
});
```

This is the tutorial I'm using for reference and things started breaking after I added Auth functions. https://thinkster.io/learn-to-build-realtime-webapps/

Clicking submit does nothing.  And when I click logout/register/login, the URL changes but that's it.

Comment: Have you created `Auth` facotry? The error seems to be that angular is not able to inject `Auth` inside your NavCtrl. Another strange thing is that your code it seems you have renamed `NavCtrl` to `AuthCtrl` Seems to me that you aren't re-building your app after making changes.

Comment: Yes, this is the auth factory https://github.com/Eibonic/AngularJS-reddit/blob/master/app/scripts/services/Auth.js

Also that was just poor format on my question.
They are properly named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included following files in your index.html?

```
<script src="scripts/services/auth.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/auth.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I did.  Checking for spelling errors and I don't see.

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was in my routes.

Maybe the tutorial code is outdated but it told me to put resolve below the templateUrl & controller